# Добавление данных в столбец Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite3

У меня есть своя бд в которой есть таблица users. В данной таблице есть столбец inventory с типом данных TEXT. Мне нужно, чтобы в этом столбце(inventory) у пользователя было несколько значений. Не просто заменилось старое значение на новое, а к старому значению добавилось новое. Например: было значение: яблоки. Потом я добавил значение апельсины, и столбец у пользователя стал такой: яблоки, апельсины. Как так добавлять к старым данным новые?

Comment: update users set inventory = inventory + " апельсины" where <условие>

Comment: бд не оперирует столбцами. бд оперирует таблицами. у вас должна быть таблица где есть значения `inventory` и `user`, например. а в `inventory` напротив яблок и ананасов в поле `user` должно стоять имя этого пользователя. у вас может быть тонна всяких овощей, привязанная к одному пользователю.

Comment: `update users set inventory=concat(inventory,',','апельсины') WHERE <условие>`

Comment: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: concat

Comment: да, может быть, я тестил на мариа_дб, метку базы не заметил, ну вроде в sqlite `||` оператор соединения строк..тогда как-нибудь так `update users set inventory=inventory || ', апельсины' WHERE <условие>`

Comment: А если мне неизвестно значение которое я буду присоединять?

Comment: ну в программе будет наверно переменная которая содержит добавляемое значение. Формируйте запрос в виде строки и в базу на исполнение.

Comment: cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET inventory = inventory || ',' {} WHERE id = {}".format(item, ctx.author.id,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "GT440": syntax error

Comment: думаю, что `inventory || ',' {} ` надо так `inventory || ',' || {} ` еще `format(item, ctx.author.id,)` запятая висячая не нравится, походу у вас пустое значение вставляется ?

Comment: я бы так попробовал  `cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET inventory = inventory || ',' || '{}' WHERE id = {}".format(item, ctx.author.id))`

Comment: Да я просто создал таблицу inventory, в нее заношу данные: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO inventory VALUES(?,?,?),(ctx.guild.id, ctx.author.id, item) Тем самый создается еще одна строка(ну ты понял) и в ней айди сервера, айди юзера и предмет